# using intent with button event

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am new to android development.  I have several posts and tutorials but I am not quite understanding using/setting up Intents.

I created an app to get a better understanding but I cant get the code to work.
My thought process is as follows

1. i setup 2 activities with fragments.
2. on my main fragment I added a button, where once clicked it goes to another activity page

Question: when I use intent do I call the fragments or the activity?

my code:

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class PlanMeMainFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mNewButton, mExistingButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planme_main_fragment, parent, false);
    return  v;


    mNewButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);
    mNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(PlanMeMainFragment.this, NewEventSetupFragment.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
      });
   }
   }
```

i have my manifest set up as

```
      <activity
        android:name=".PlanMeMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewEventSetupActivity">

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invoke a Activity from the Fragment. As calling class you need to set the Activity that hosts the Fragment. You get that with getActivity().
If you want to call the 2nd Activity from the 1st Fragment (that lies on your first Activity) you go like that:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

In that Activity you just invoked you can instanciate the Fragment just as you did with your first one. But are you sure you need a second Activity? You could just host both Fragments on your Activity and replace the first with the second one (just FYI if you didn't know).

Comment: when i change the line to above (@tritop), my line that says mButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_event_button;   gives an unreachable statement error?  What does that mean?

Comment: @hozdaman: Thats your next error, I didn't see that in first place. You are returning v right before it, that means the code below that return is never reached. You need to put that return v; line at the bottom, right before the closing bracket of onCreateView(). Its always the last thing you do in onCreateView.

Comment: @tritop--thank you so much for your help, that was it.

Comment: @hozdaman  
Glad I could help. It would be be nice to mark my answer as correct by clicking that checkmark right beyond the votecounter to the left of the post.

Comment: hi i was wondering if you can help me out a little more. when i go to press the button in the emulator nothing happens it should go to another activity but it does does nothing.  I have the second activity is listed in my manifest.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(PlanMeMainFragment.this, NewEventSetupActivity.class);
```

To switch between activities, you take the activity.